# Azure Storage Emulator's queues not loading

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-emulator

I'm new to Azure Storage and I've been having a problem creating and working with queues locally.
So, firstly I wasn't able to make the Azure Storage Emulator run, so I've changed the config to look like this:

```
<StorageEmulatorConfig>
<services>
  <service name="Blob" url="http://localhost:10000/"/>
  <service name="Queue" url="http://localhost:10001/"/>
  <service name="Table" url="http://localhost:10002/"/>
</services>
```

(Originally it had a 127.0.0.1 IP instead of localhost). That change made the Storage Emulator run correctly, but I still only get an endless loading icon when trying to ellapse the Queues (and Blob containers and Tables too, by the way).

So far I've tried:

1. Creating a new azure storage connection with the same connection string, but replacing the default IP with localhost.
   2.Changing the number of the ports in the config file
2. Restarting everything
3. Reinstalling Azure Storage Explorer and Emulator

Have you guys ever encountered this type of error, or have any idea what could I try to fix it?

**Edit:** I have also deleted the .IdentityService folder from my machine. No luck.

Comment: Please edit your question and include: 1) Versions of Storage Emulator and Storage Explorer. 2) Are you able to see blob containers and tables?

Comment: Hi Gaurav. I'm using the latest of both (1.10.1 for Explorer, and 5.10.0 for Storage Emulator). I cannot see the blob containers and tables. In fact, if I try to access the tables, it throws the following error: Network Timeout Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10002.

Comment: Can you ensure that the storage emulator is running? Also, please check if any other processes are using storage emulator ports.

Comment: @GauravMantri the ports are not being used by any other project. IsRunning is marked as true if I run the status command in the console, and I can also hit the endpoint if I put http://localhost:10001 in the browser, but I get an 404 if I use the IP I mentioned earlier.